# Error posicionamiento

Tags: html

Tengo dos div, el primero contiene una imagen, el segundo es un slider. El problema que tengo es en el href del slider, al hacer click en las imagenes no se mantiene en su sitio, si no que se pone en parte superior de la pantalla. Es decir tambien pasa por encima del otro DIV creo que mi error es en el href, pero no se como ponerlo para que se mantenga en su sitio.

````
    <img src="./img/logo 1.1.png" alt="NESE BEAUTY STUDIO">
    </div>
    <div class="containerr">   
        <ul class="slider">
            <li id="slide1">
                <img src="./img/image_6483441 1.11.JPG" alt="nese-beauty-studio">
            </li>
            <li id="slide2">
                <img src="./img/image_5073664  1 1.12.JPG" alt="nese-beauty-studio">
            </li>
            <li id="slide3">
                <img src="./img/image_6483441 1.13.JPG" alt="nese-beauty-studio">
            </li>
            <li id="slide4"> 
                <img src="./img/image_6483441 1.14.JPG" alt="nese-beauty-studio">
            </li>
            <li id="slide5">
                <img src="./img/image_6483441  1.15.JPG" alt="nese-beauty-studio">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="menu-slider"> 
            <li id="me-slid">
                <a href="#slider/slide1">1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#slide2 ">2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#slide3">3</a>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <a href="#slide4">4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#slide5">5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div> ```
````

Comment: Sugiero probar cambiando los nombres de las imágenes. Los navegadores no resuelven correctamente los espacios en los nombres de archivo.

Comment: Los dos <ul> tienen por objetivo que debajo de cada imagen se muestre un link correspondiente a esa imagen? Sí es así link e imagen deberían estar contenidos en el mismo <li>.

Comment: No se si fue al colocar el código acá, pero tienes casi al inicio una línea que dice `<div class="containerr">` (con doble 'r')  y debe ser 'container' (una sola 'r')